# How to load a view from didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

my first screen shows a number of Customized **cells** which contains 3 labels.
i want to load a **detailView** on selecting one of the rows.
what code should i use in **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** of my firstViewController??
also explain where and what changes to do at other places
thank you!!

Comment: This is a Q&A site, Zaraki, and not a place for tutorials. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of what you can do :

```
YourDetailViewController* detailVC = [[YourDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@YourDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC];
[detailVC release];
```

Comment: on clicking the row the view doesn't load simulator exits..
and console shows:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DetailViewController initWithNibName:bundle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Don't forget to release it after it has been pushed onto to the stack!